# React: My state variable not defined every time initiate

Tags: reactjs

Every time I initialize my React project, there is an error saying the state variable is not defined. Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

This is a create-react-app project

```````````````````
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user : [],
            }
        ender(){
        return(
              <div>
                Welcome, 
              {this.state.user.length !==0 
               ? this.state.user.name : ''}
              </div>
       )}
``````````````````
```````````````````

Comment: move the `render` function out the constructor

Comment: I can see a typo ender => render